# RecyclerView SearchView giving wrong URL onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, position, searchview

I've been struggling to get the correct position of an URL on a RecyclerView. I use the FCM to get data and store it on SharedPreference. I implement a SearchView to my RecyclerView to filter an specific word, it works ok.

The problem is when you search for that word and then you click on the recyclerView, it send you to the url on the first position of the original recyclerView, not the filtered one. I tried to change the position on my BindViewHolder, but it doesn't seem to work. Also to change the position also on my onClick function inside my ViewHolder but doesn't ether, it might be because the onClick function requires an Int and it founds what I have on Notificaciones
[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYOAy.png) and when I change it to Notificaciones on my Interface the onClick stops working.

**This is my Adapter**

```
class NotifAdapter(private var mContext: Context, items:ArrayList<Notificaciones>, var listener: onClickListenerForAdapter): RecyclerView.Adapter<NotifAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var items: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null
var itemsFiltered: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null

init {
    this.items = items
    this.itemsFiltered = items

}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotifAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val vista = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cv_notif, parent, false)
    val viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista,listener)

    return viewHolder
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemsFiltered?.count()!!
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotifAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = itemsFiltered?.get(position)
    holder.title?.text = item?.title
    holder.body?.text = item?.body
    holder.fecha?.text = item?.fecha
    holder.img?.setImageResource(item?.img!!)


    //Animaciones para la imagen
    holder.img?.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.aparecer_animacion)

    //Animación para el mensaje
    holder.mensaje?.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.crecer_animacion)

}

inner class ViewHolder(vista:View, listener:onClickListenerForAdapter): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista), View.OnClickListener{
    var vista  = vista
    var title: TextView? = null
    var body: TextView? = null
    var fecha: TextView? = null
    var listener:onClickListenerForAdapter? = null
    var img: ImageView? = null
    var mensaje:RelativeLayout? = null
     var items: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null
     var itemsFiltered: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null


    init {
        title = vista.findViewById(R.id.tituloNotif)
        body = vista.findViewById(R.id.textNotif)
        fecha = vista.findViewById(R.id.fechaNotif)
        img = vista.findViewById(R.id.imgNotif)
        mensaje = vista.findViewById(R.id.contenido)
        this.listener = listener
        vista.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        val adapterPosition = itemsFiltered?.get(adapterPosition)
        this.listener?.onClick(v!!, adapterPosition)

    }
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val Key = constraint.toString()
            itemsFiltered = if (Key.isEmpty()) {
                items
            } else {
                val lstFiltered = java.util.ArrayList<Notificaciones>()
                for (row in items!!) {
                    if (row.title.toLowerCase().contains(Key.toLowerCase()) || row.body.toLowerCase().contains(Key.toLowerCase())) {
                        lstFiltered.add(row)
                    }
                }
                lstFiltered
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = itemsFiltered
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
            itemsFiltered = results.values as java.util.ArrayList<Notificaciones>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}}
```

**This is my Notificaciones class**

```
class Notificaciones(title: String, body: String, fecha: String, imagen: Int){

var title = ""
var body = ""
var fecha = ""
var img = 0
init {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.fecha = fecha
    this.img = imagen
}
```

}

**This is the interface I for my RecyclerView**

```
interface onClickListenerForAdapter {
fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int)
```

}

**This is my Activity class**

```
class ventanaNotif : AppCompatActivity() {

val notifList = ArrayList<Notificaciones>()
var lista:RecyclerView? = null
lateinit var adaptador: NotifAdapter
var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
lateinit var shared: SharedPreferences
private val COUNT_KEY = "Conteo"
var busqueda: EditText?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventana_notif)

    //findViews
    lista = findViewById(R.id.rv_notif) //RecyclerView nuevo
    busqueda = findViewById(R.id.busqueda)//Busqueda de texto

    //Nuevo RecyclerView
    lista?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    lista?.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adaptador = NotifAdapter(this ,notifList, object:onClickListenerForAdapter{

            override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {


                val url = notifList.get(index).fecha.toString()
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                startActivity(i)
        }

    })
    lista?.adapter = adaptador


    //funciones
    notifData()


    butBorrar.setOnClickListener {
        shared.edit().clear().apply()
        adaptador.notifyItemRemoved(adaptador.itemCount)
    }

    //Metodo de busqueda por TextWatcher
    busqueda?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            adaptador.filter.filter(s)
        }
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        }
    })
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ventanaHome::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
    super.onBackPressed()
}

fun notifData() {

    shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY, 0)

    for ((x, valor) in (1..count).withIndex()) {
        notifList.add(
            Notificaciones(
                "${shared.getString("TituloData${valor}", "Todo bien")}",
                "${shared.getString("CuerpoData${valor}", "No hay más notificaciones")}",
                "${shared.getString("UrlData${valor}", "Sin URL ")}", R.drawable.ic_steren2)
        )

        adaptador.notifyItemInserted(adaptador.itemCount)
    }
}}
```

When I change my interface Like this

```
interface onClickListenerForAdapter {

fun onClick(vista: View, notificaciones: Notificaciones)}
```

The onClick on my Activity stops working, because lacks of index to get fecha from notifList.

```
adaptador = NotifAdapter(this ,notifList, object:onClickListenerForAdapter{

        override fun onClick(vista: View, notificaciones: Notificaciones) {


            val url = notifList.get(index).fecha.toString()
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse(url)
            startActivity(i)}
```

I was hopping you could spot the error. Any help will be very much appreciated

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me.

1. Delete the interface and use a onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder.

> ```
>  holder.vista.setOnClickListener{
>                 if(url!= ""){
>                     val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
>                     i.data = Uri.parse(url)
>                     mContext.startActivity(i)
>                 } else {
>                     Toast.makeText(mContext,"No hay archivos adjuntos :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
>                 }}
> ```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Your interface has this definition:

```kotlin
interface onClickListenerForAdapter {
    fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int)
}
```

And you're not passing the adapter position as 2nd argument - you are passing `Notificationes` object that you are getting from the list:

```kotlin
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    val adapterPosition = itemsFiltered?.get(adapterPosition)
    this.listener?.onClick(v!!, adapterPosition)
}
```

So you need to either change your interface to this:

```kotlin
interface onClickListenerForAdapter {
    fun onClick(vista: View, notificationes: Notificaciones)
}
```

or change the `onClick` method to this:

```kotlin
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    this.listener?.onClick(v!!, adapterPosition)
}
```

And what you actually have right now in the onClick method should rather be named like this:

```kotlin
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    val notificationes = itemsFiltered?.get(adapterPosition)
    this.listener?.onClick(v!!, notificationes)
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mariusz. I already did this, and forget to explain that the onClick funtion stop in my Activity Class. See up